# asp.net mvc routing issue redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to create a route that redirects to urls but can't get it to work for the life of me. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class GoAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Go";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea( AreaRegistrationContext context )
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Go/Issues",
            "go/issues/{issueID}",
            new { controller = "Go", action = "GoIssues" },
            new { issueID = @"\d+" }
        );
    }
}
```

and my controller:

```
public class GoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GoIssues( int issueID )
    {
      var version = getVersion( issueID );
      if( version != null )
      {
        string url = MakeUrl(version, issueID);

        // Redirect to the right url
        return Redirect( url );
      }
    }

    // not found
    return HttpNotFound();
  }
}
```

The whole point of this is to determine the right version to redirect to and to redirect there. But for some reason go/issues/123 gives me a 404 not found. I used the route debug tool and it shows that this route is hit but when I disable it, I'm back to 404.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else is having the same problem, I've found the answer.

After much googling, I found the following article that explains how routing works.

> http://blog.davebouwman.com/2011/12/08/asp-net-mvc3-and-404s-for-area-controllers/

The article says that ASP.NET is expecting the namespace to be a certain format:

> The issue was the namespace on my controller. Turns out that MVC has a convention that the area name is expected to be in the namespace of the controller.
>
> So – I had StatsMe.API.CategoriesController, but MVC was looking for StatsMe.Areas.API.CategoriesController.
>
> What finally tipped me off was some stuff in the RouteDebugger output…
>
> Annoying because the error message really could have helped out by saying “Hey – I’m looking for StatsMe.Areas.API.CategoriesController and I can’t find it”, rather than the very generic message it spit out.

Answer (score 1):

Try put your route in the global route configuration instead of area registration and see if works .

I've tried using your configuration on my test project, it's working fine. If this still doesn't work,  I would suggest to start small and make it work, then slowly adding your route configuration onto it until a point it breaks.

Comment: thanks but area registration works for me for everything else but this.